# How do I use a for loop to apply a multi-argument function to a data frame based on a grouping variable?

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, subset, scalability

## Preamble

I apologize in advance, I find it very difficult to express in writing the exact problem and think it is most clear by looking at the code. Also, I am relatively new to R and have trouble using the right words to accurately describe the situation. I think the solution should be easy to point out by someone with a bit more experience, any advice would be much appreciated!

## Description

I have a specialized calculation that I am trying to make on a group-by-group basis for which I have written a function. The function is user-defined to execute this specialized calculation, requires 4 arguments (2 of which have a length >1) and outputs a single value (so the output does not equal the length of the input). While this function does work, I need to be able to efficiently apply it to each group in a data frame (for the reproducible example below there are 4 groups but, in reality, there will be 100s or 1000s of groups).

I've tried to use the apply functions, which are often recommended for situations that sound similar to this, but I have so far been unsuccessful in using a non-for loop approach. I think this is because each row in the data frame is not associated with a different group, rather there are multiple rows associated with a single group (for the reproducible example below there are 21 rows associated with each group, which is the same as the actual data).

Regardless, it seemed like a for loop would be a straightforward way to apply my function to the rows associated with each group. However, I am unable to generate the desired output. As I alluded to in the preamble, I think it is just because I am overlooking/unaware of something very fundamental, such as the need to do a loop inside a loop or index my for loop differently.

## Reproducible Example

#### Functionally similar data

```
interval=0.05 #used here to generate v1 and again in the function
v1 = seq(0.00000000001,1.00000000001, by=interval) 
nrows = length(v1) #determines length of other variables
g1 = c(rep(23.4, nrows), rep(19.7, nrows),rep(25.2, nrows),rep(16.4, 
nrows))           
v2 = runif(length(g1), 0,1)
dat = as.data.frame(cbind(g1,v1,v2))
```

Where:

- g1 is the grouping variable
- v1 is the first argument, repeats for each grouping var
- v2 is  the second argument, represents a probability associated with each v1
- dat is the data frame

#### The Function

(This is my first function and I assume there is a better way to write it but it does work)

```
MyFunction = function(v1, v2, interval, nrows) {
  sum.prod = sum(v1[2:nrows-1] * v2[2:nrows-1])
  last.val = v2[nrows]/2
  out = 2 * (sum.prod+last.val) * interval
  out
  }
```

#### Proof that the function works

I am providing the calculation for the first grouping variable (g1=23.4) just in case it is helpful to confirm that the function works and how it works since there is no documentation for this function

```
range1 = 1:nrows
g1.sub1 = dat$g1[range1]
v1.sub1 = dat$v1[range1]
v2.sub1 = dat$v2[range1]

g.first = 2 * ((v1.sub1[2] * v2.sub1[2])+
(v1.sub1[3] * v2.sub1[3]) + (v1.sub1[4] * v2.sub1[4]) +
(v1.sub1[5] * v2.sub1[5]) + (v1.sub1[6] * v2.sub1[6]) +
(v1.sub1[7] * v2.sub1[7]) + (v1.sub1[8] * v2.sub1[8]) +
(v1.sub1[9] * v2.sub1[9]) + (v1.sub1[10] * v2.sub1[10]) +
(v1.sub1[11] * v2.sub1[11]) + (v1.sub1[12] * v2.sub1[12]) +
(v1.sub1[13] * v2.sub1[13]) + (v1.sub1[14] * v2.sub1[14]) +
(v1.sub1[15] * v2.sub1[15]) + (v1.sub1[16] * v2.sub1[16]) +
(v1.sub1[17] * v2.sub1[17]) + (v1.sub1[18] * v2.sub1[18]) +
(v1.sub1[19] * v2.sub1[19]) + (v1.sub1[20] * v2.sub1[20]) +
v2.sub1[21] / 2) * interval

g.first
```

Which matches the value given by:

```
MyFunction(v1 = v1.sub1, v2 = v2.sub1, interval = interval, nrows=nrows)
```

#### Where I am Stuck: The For Loop

As I alluded to in the description, I've tried various approaches to solve this problem including the apply family of functions without luck. The following code represents the closest that I have come. However, this only gives me the correct value for the first element in g1 (23.4) four times rather than the correct value for each of the four elements in g1 (23.4, 19.9.25.2,16.4) one time.

```
g=c(unique((g1)))
out=NULL
for(i in seq_along(g)){
out[i]=MyFunction( v1 = v1, v2 = v2, interval = interval, nrows = 
nrows)
}
out
```

#### Attempt to Troubleshoot the For Loop

I can force the above for loop to produce something similar to the desired results, but the range must be specified for each group and since the actual data has 100s of groups rather than just 4 groups and the total number of groups is not known in advance this is not a workable solution.

```
g=c(unique((g1)))

range1 = 1:nrows
range2 = (nrows+1):(nrows*2)
range3 = (nrows*2+1):(nrows*3)
range4 = (nrows*3+1):(nrows*4)

out1=NULL
out2=NULL
out3=NULL
out4=NULL

for(i in seq_along(g)){
out1[i]=MyFunction( v1 = dat$v1[range1], v2 = dat$v2[range1], 
interval = interval, nrows = nrows)
out2[i]=MyFunction( v1 = dat$v1[range2], v2 = dat$v2[range2], 
interval = interval, nrows = nrows)
out3[i]=MyFunction( v1 = dat$v1[range3], v2 = dat$v2[range3], 
interval = interval, nrows = nrows)
out4[i]=MyFunction( v1 = dat$v1[range4], v2 = dat$v2[range4], 
interval = interval, nrows = nrows)
}

out1
out2
out3
out4
```

#### The Desired Output

Ideally, the final output would be a table/matrix/list/data frame that contains each value of g1 and the associated value output by the function "out"

Something like:

```
g1      out
23.4    some value between 0 and 1
19.9    some value between 0 and 1
25.2    some value between 0 and 1
16.4    some value between 0 and 1
```

#### Concluding Thoughts

Since my "Attempt to Troubleshoot the For Loop" was ultimately able to provide the correct outputs, albeit in an undesirable way (labor intensive, not scalable, and it outputs 4 identical values for each group rather than 1 value for each group), I think this indicates that my code is lacking something fundamental (e.g., another loop, a different variable for seq_along, improper indexing, etc.). I hope this is easy for a more experienced user to identify and explain as I am stumped.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you asked for a for loop but as you've probably seen before, there's usually a better way to do it. I guess you're not familiar with the `data.table` package yet, think of it as a  supercharged `data.frame`.

So what you want to do is to apply `MyFunction` to your data, grouped by the column `g1`. This can be easily achieved in `data.table` in the following way.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[, .(out = MyFunction(v1, v2, interval, .N)), by = g1]
```

So what these lines do is first load the library (you might have to install it first with `install.packages('data.table')`. Then convert your `data.frame` to a `data.table`. Finally, compute the column `out` as `MyFunction` applied to `v1, v2, interval and .N` (think of `.N` as nrows) grouped by `g1`.

I think this achieves your goal, if you have any questions feel free to ask. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the tidyverse.

First, let's look at the example, replacing MyFunction with a few lines that capture the summarization process you describe:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  slice(1:21) %>%  # Just the first grouping variable
  slice(2:n()) %>% # Exclude first row; has small impact since v1[1] is nearly zero already...
  mutate(prod = if_else(row_number() < n(),  # For all rows but the last one in the group,
                        v1 * v2,             # ... get the product of v1 and v2
                        v2/2)) %>%           # ... or have of v2, for the last row
  summarize(out = 2 * sum(prod) * interval)  # Sum the "prod" row, * 2 * interval

#        out
#1 0.5980449
```

To do this for all groups of g1, we'd add `group_by` first, and then do the same summarization steps separately for each group:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(g1) %>%
  slice(1:21) %>%  # Just the first grouping variable
  slice(2:n()) %>% # Exclude first row; has small impact since v1[1] is nearly zero already...
  mutate(prod = if_else(row_number() < n(),  # For all rows but the last one in the group,
                        v1 * v2,             # ... get the product of v1 and v2
                        v2/2)) %>%           # ... or have of v2, for the last row
  summarize(out = 2 * sum(prod) * interval)  # Sum the "prod" row, * 2 * interval

## A tibble: 4 x 2
#     g1   out
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  16.4 0.342
#2  19.7 0.514
#3  23.4 0.598
#4  25.2 0.568
```